# Can I show "small" 320x50 iAd banners on the iPad?

Tags: cocoa-touch, ipad, iad

Since in my country there are very few (if any) iAd banners for iPad, I'd rather prefer to show those for iPhone. I know they are small and not optimized for the iPad, but at least they allow me to monetize even the iPad version of my app.

The `requiredContentSizeIdentifiers` property of `ADBannerView` accepts these values:

```
extern NSString * const ADBannerContentSizeIdentifier320x50;
extern NSString * const ADBannerContentSizeIdentifier480x32;
extern NSString * const ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait;
extern NSString * const ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierLandscape;
```

but the first two (`ADBannerContentSizeIdentifier320x50` and `ADBannerContentSizeIdentifier480x32`) are deprecated.

If on the iPad I set `ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait` the banner size becomes 768x66.

Is it possible to show "small" 320x50 iAd banners on the iPad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can but I was reading this a couple of days ago:

http://www.hung-truong.com/blog/2011/02/07/iad-vs-admob-clicks-fill-rate-impressions-ecpm-and-revenue/

Basically get your app 'signed up' to two ad streams so that there'll almost always be something displayed.

I haven't tried myself as I'm lucky enough with my fill rate but I hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If it were possible I would use only iAd, because it is better integrated in the app and in my opinion offers a better user experience than AdMob.